# Plugin loads its scripts but does not apply

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, plugins

I created a WordPress theme from a PSD and tryed to install the '**Monarch Social Sharing Plugin**'.

The plugin install fine and load all scripts (js) and CSS files, I see on the Network tab on the developer tools in the browser.

I have put the wp_head() before the  and wp_footer() before the

On the content page I can see the info about the share count that the plugin generate, but without styles.

If I try to load by hand the css files on the header file I see some styles but with broken areas.

I have read all the 'Theme Development' (https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) but I didn't not found my mistake.

This same plugin works fine on the default wordpress theme and others themes.

Any suggestion?

Link of the page: http://dev.quadradigital.com.br/isd/

Comment: I can't offer any suggestions but I can tell you that I giggled when I read the title. Inanimate objects don't have genders in English, so the plugin isn't a "he", it's an "it". Eg. `Plugin loads its scripts but does not apply`

Comment: Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 0):

You missed to mention below code in you custom theme header.php

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

In this function only fetch all plugin and theme enqueue scripts in website.

Comment: Sorry, I mean wp_head() on my code not wp_header(). So I have the wp_head() on my header.php

Comment: Yes, one about the bootstrap.min.js:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
But I dont think it's the cause.

You can take a look on the site here: http://dev.quadradigital.com.br/isd/